# Как на Андроид используя Google Maps API v2 получить район города по координатам?

Tags: android, google-maps-api, java

Встал вопрос.
В разрабатываемом мною приложении используется геокодирование и геодекодировангие. Определение страны, города, улицы номера дома работает прекрасно! Но сейчас необходимо по координатам определить также район города. Проверил при вводе названия районов гугл их выводит(имею ввиду на сайте: maps.google.com), а как его получить программно ума не приложу и нигде не могу найти подобной информации! Буду рад любой помощи!
Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 4):

Все нашел! Всем спасибо!

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Address.html

```
getSubLocality()
```

Returns the sub-locality of the address, or null if it is unknown.